Entries Live Preview Only Reflects Changes After 'Save' and Not On Drafts
I just started using CraftCMS Pro 5.4.6 without access to the backend (only Control Panel), so did my limited research to the best of my ability.
When I'm creating entries, the 'Preview' button successfully pulls up the edit panel and website side by side, but will not reflect any changes until I hit 'Save'. Some changes I've tried: updating texts, disabling/enabling content blocks, inserting images, etc. This is not the expected behavior of the 'Preview' button from what I've read (it should be automatically saving changes to a draft which appears in the preview panel). I see the page reload when I make changes, but no changes are reflected visually.
I've also tried using the preview panel on a draft, where no changes are reflected in the Preview panel even after I hit save.
I tried looking at Chrome Inspector for any potential errors, and with my limited understanding of API calls, nothing stood out as a failed POST/GET.
Would appreciate any advice, context, etc! Thank you :)

Do you have any CKEditor fields with embedded entries, or matrix fields set to cards view? I.e., are you double-clicking on cards and then editing fields in a dialogue box? In this case, the preview only refreshes once you hit save in the dialogue box. I think this is the intended behaviour at the moment, but I also think it is broken from an author's perspective.
I've opened two issues on this topic:

For Matrix fields: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/16295
For CKEditor fields: https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/issues/331

If this is the same problem you're seeing, you can upvote or add a comment with your perspective to give those issues some visibility.

Thank you so much for making those issues! I believe I'm using matrix fields as cards, but I don't get the secondary popup to edit each card like what was shown in the video. The only save button I have access to is the one for the entire page, which brings me out of preview every time I hit it. I would honestly be happy with accessing a secondary popup like shown in your video atp! I have tried 'Open in new tab', but even after hitting save in that, no changes are reflected in the preview after. Not sure what's going on there either

@redstrawb Hm, I don't quite understand your setup from your description. Maybe you can add a screen recording of the problem to your question? Then it will be easier to see what's going on and whether it's related to my issues linked above.
